# How to copy a jar file from a folder located at myfolder/folderName to urs/lib/jvm/java-1.8/jre/lib/etc In Fedora Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora

Need suggestion on Fedora Linux to copy a jar file. I have this jar file at a location myFolder/folderName and trying to copy that jar in location at urs/lib/jvm/java-1.8/jre/lib/etc. when I do pwd, I am right now at location urs/lib/jvm/java-1.8/jre/lib/etc.  what command I use to copy that jar to this location. I would apprecate your help.

Comment: `cp` - copy files and directories. see `man cp`

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it belongs on Super User rather than StackOverflow

Comment: @MarcoLucidi: I know cp is for copy but I don't know what the total command would be. Note: I am at urs/lib/jvm/java-1.8/jre/lib/etc when I do pwd.

Comment: if you are already inside destination folder, then `cp /foo/bar/my.jar .` where `.` means "current directory", but again, see `man cp` to learn how to use the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want the cp command.  it copies what ever you specify in the first argument to the second arguements location.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cp-command-linux-examples/

sudo cp myFolder/folderName/somefile urs/lib/jvm/java-1.8/jre/lib/etc

Comment: Thanks @Dani-rae. It worked.